# Maximum number of devices allowed to use the same Outlook account

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, office365, outlook-restapi

What's the **maximum number of devices that can use an Outlook account at the same time**?
I need to keep an Office365 user logged in (for months) on 7 tablets at the same time plus sporadically access it from a browser.

**Context**:
I'm developing and Android application, based on [outlook-sdk-android](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/android), that talks with the [Outlook Calendar REST Api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations). The app uses an [Office REST Client for Android](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-SDK-Android/blob/master/sdk/outlook-services/src/main/java/com/microsoft/services/outlook/fetchers/OutlookClient.java) (a shared client stack provided by [orc-for-android](https://github.com/msopentech/orc-for-android)) .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK,the Exchange(thats where the calendar function is accessible) ActiveSync device limit is 100. Here is a reference:

[Exchange Online Limits](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange-online-limits.aspx#BKMK_ExchangeActiveSync_Limits)

Comment: Is it the same for Outlook API? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to login 15 times the same user on the same device and it worked.

Tried to login on 6 different emulators at the same time + 2 real devices and worked.